# primary key to foreign key to foreign/primary

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

there are tables in database like

```
tbl_items
item_id        item_batch         item_name
```

(primay key = item_id+item_batch)

```
tbl_transaction(orders)_header
ordre_id      employe_id       date
```

(primary key= order_id)

```
tbl_transaction_(orders)detail
(id)blind   order_id         item_code     item_batch  item_qty
```

(primary key= blind mean identy column) (foreign key = item_code+item_batch from tbl_items)

```
tbl_warehouse
item_code      Item_batch       item_qty
```

primary key(item_code+item_batch)

**confusion here** 

**i--**foreign key(item_code+item_batch to item_code+item_batch from tbl_transaction_detial )

**or this is correct**

**ii--**
foreign key(item_code+item_batch to item_code+item_batch from tbl_items )

the process is as fellow user create new bill whose id and current date will be stored in **transaction_header** and the item customer buy their detail will be stored in **transaction details**  and then update warehouse table

now if the record exist in **transaction header** then update **warehouse**

according to this what will be the correct foreign key relation ship **i or ii**

Comment: your question is not specific. what does `(orders)` means.? is that in name? not able to understand from `tbl_transaction_(orders)detail`

Comment: here you can replace transaction with orders

Comment: This question is really great confusing..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So sorting out your first confusion:

**Foreign Key** of `transaction_table` will point to **Primary key** of `table_item`.

or in better way you can say that.

**Foreign Key** of `transaction_table` `references` **Primary key** of `table_item`.

And as per your question:

**i)** Your `transaction_header` will not contain any `Foreign Key`. I mean it do not need any `Foreign Key`.

**ii)** `Foreign Key` from `transaction_detail` will reference to `Primary key` of `table_item`.

**iii)** `Foreign Key` of `transaction_detail` will reference to `Primary Key` of `warehouse`.

As change in the `transaction_detail` is causing changes in `warehouse` and `item_table`.

**For better understanding read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp).**